# Чому деякі закони явно вказують номер частин в статті а деякі не вказують?

Tags: стилістика

Наприклад [стаття 185 Кримінального кодексу України](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2341-14#n1209) явним чином  містить  п'ять частин.

> Стаття 185. Крадіжка
>
> 1. Таємне викрадення чужого майна (крадіжка) -
>
>    карається штрафом від однієї тисячі до трьох тисяч неоподатковуваних мінімумів доходів громадян або громадськими роботами на строк від вісімдесяти до двохсот сорока годин, або виправними роботами на строк до двох років, або арештом на строк до шести місяців, або обмеженням волі на строк до п’яти років.
> 2. Крадіжка, вчинена повторно або за попередньою змовою групою осіб, -
>
>    карається арештом на строк від трьох до шести місяців або обмеженням волі на строк до п'яти років або позбавленням волі на той самий строк.
> 3. Крадіжка, поєднана з проникненням у житло, інше приміщення чи сховище або що завдала значної шкоди потерпілому, -
>
>    карається позбавленням волі на строк від трьох до шести років.
> 4. Крадіжка, вчинена у великих розмірах чи в умовах воєнного або надзвичайного стану, -
>
>    карається позбавленням волі на строк від п'яти до восьми років.
> 5. Крадіжка, вчинена в особливо великих розмірах або організованою групою, -
>
>    карається позбавленням волі на строк від семи до дванадцяти років з конфіскацією майна.

Проте [інші закони](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/3857-12#n34), як нижче явно не вказують частини статті в тексті, але опосередковано на них посилаються (в частині змін закону).

> Стаття 6. Підстави для тимчасового обмеження права громадян України на виїзд з України
> {Назва статті 6 в редакції Закону № 1474-VIII від 14.07.2016}
> Право громадянина України на виїзд з України може бути тимчасово обмежено у випадках, коли:
>
> {Абзац перший частини першої статті 6 із змінами, внесеними згідно із Законом № 888-VIII від 10.12.2015; в редакції Закону № 1474-VIII від 14.07.2016}
>
> 1. він обізнаний з відомостями, які становлять державну таємницю, - до закінчення терміну, встановленого статтею 12 цього Закону;
>
> {Пункт 2 **частини першої** статті 6 виключено на підставі Закону № 888-VIII від 10.12.2015} .....

Чи відомо чому так відбувається, як "правильно" має бути та чи є правильна структура?

На мою думку безпосередньо вкзані частини статті спрощують сприяння тексту.

Це важливо для проекту https://chitkyi-zakon.org

Comment: Я виправив форматування тексту, щоб не вилазило за межі екрану, але ви маєте значно скоротити цитату, бо вичитувати цю стіну тексту геть неможливо.

Comment: Дуже дякую за редагування, та поради :)
Я скоротив